# Atributo que va variando con las iteraciones

Tags: array, lista

tengo este trozo de código:

```
private List<String> cachedRouteMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Route> cachedRoutes = new ArrayList<Route>();

public List<Route> getRoutes(DataBaseHelper db) {//Saca la lista de marcardores
    Cursor nombreruta = db.nombreruta();
    for (nombreruta.moveToFirst(); !nombreruta.isAfterLast(); nombreruta.moveToNext()) {//Va recorriendo la base de datos por el nombre de ruta

        Cursor wp = db.waypoints(nombreruta.getString(0));//Extrae los waypoints
        for (wp.moveToFirst(); !wp.isAfterLast(); wp.moveToNext()) {
            cachedRouteMarkers.add(wp.getString(0));//Va añadiendo los waypoints
        }
        cachedRoutes.add(new Route(nombreruta.getString(0),cachedRouteMarkers,Color.RED));//Va añadiendo las rutas
        cachedRouteMarkers.clear();
    }
    return cachedRoutes;
}
```

El método `getRoutes(DatabaseHelper db)` va sacando strings de una base de datos y los va metiendo en `cachedRouteMarkers`. Después voy creando un objeto del tipo `Route`, utilizando lo anterior como atributo y lo voy almacenando en `cachedRoutes`. Yo quiero que el número de Strings de `cachedRouteMarkers` en cada `Route` se quede fijo, pero con cada iteración se va modificando.

¿Cómo puedo hacer que se quede fijo y no se modifique?

Muchas gracias de antemano :)

Comment: Ah! En general es muy útil incluir el tag del lenguaje de programación que usas para que la gente con experiencia en él lo vea.

Comment: Lo siento, soy muuy nueva en esto y hay cosas que se me pasan por alto, pero...HAS DADO EN EL CLAVO!! MUCHÍSIMAS GRACIAS!! No sé como algo tan simple se me ha pasado...Mil gracias de nuevo!

Comment: @MDolores, si ese código es en C#, te recomiendo colocar 3 barras diagonales encima del método para colocar comentarios. Además `nombreruta.moveToFirst()` no estoy seguro qué información contiene. [edit] la pregunta con ejemplos de información. ¿`nombreruta` y `wp` tienen siempre la misma cantidad de datos? Yo te recomendaría hacer un `for` sencillo. Ejemplo: `for (int i = 0; i < nombreruta.Count; i++) { /* ... */ }`.

Answer (score 0):

La explicación que das no es la mejor del mundo, pero deduzco que lo que te pasa es que acabas con todos los `Route`s con los mismos "markers".

Lo que pasa es que estás pasando la misma instancia `cachedRouteMarkers` a cada instancia de `Route`. `clear()` te limpia el estado interno de la instancia que tienes, pero sigues trabajando con la misma instancia.

Lo que tienes que hacer es crear una nueva instancia de `CachedRouteMarker` en cada iteración, de forma que no se mezclen los datos de `Route` diferentes.

Así

```
for (nombreruta.moveToFirst(); !nombreruta.isAfterLast(); nombreruta.moveToNext()) {//Va recorriendo la base de datos por el nombre de ruta
    List<String> cachedRouteMarkers = new ArrayList<>(); // Un ArrayList nuevo para cada iteración/Route
                          // No parece que tenga sentido hacer de
                          // esta variable una variable de instancia, sino que debería ser local.
                          // Considera eliminar la definición de la variable de instancia.
    Cursor wp = db.waypoints(nombreruta.getString(0));//Extrae los waypoints
    for (wp.moveToFirst(); !wp.isAfterLast(); wp.moveToNext()) {
        cachedRouteMarkers.add(wp.getString(0));//Va añadiendo los waypoints
    }
    cachedRoutes.add(new Route(nombreruta.getString(0),cachedRouteMarkers,Color.RED));//Va añadiendo las rutas
}
```